# Uncaught type error: Cannot set the property of "Callback Client" and $m is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a learner of the field of Web development. I work on a project in which I face the following problems.Here I want to add, "mowbly" API is used.

***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'CallbackClient' of undefined***

```
 bridge.CallbackClient = new CallbackClient();
```

***Uncaught ReferenceError: $m is not defined***

```
var PACKS = new PacksModel();

$m.juci.addDataset(PACKS, true);
```

***Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings***

I don't understand what to do.Please help me.I am sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the path of all js. I have a same problem. Then I fixed it by correcting the path.

Answer (score 0):

Here the `bridge` variable has not been defined, maybe it's supposed to be set  in an async call and therefore this code runs before async call completes.

`bridge.CallbackClient = new CallbackClient();`

Same problem here:
`$m.juci.addDataset(PACKS, true);`

`$m` has not been defined.

How are you defining these variables?

Comment: how to define $m?

Comment: Well, that depends on what it is that you need to define. Can you post more of your code here?

Comment: please give me your email.i will send you the whole file

Comment: renanlnobile@gmail.com

Comment: email sent. Please check :)